# Maatkit shows the MySQL replication error in one table, but won't fix it

Tags: mysql, replication, percona-tools, maatkit

We use MySQL 5.1 with a primary/secondary replication setup. I use [mk-table-checksum from Maatkit](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-table-checksum.html) to generate checksums on the master and perform consistency checks on the replica.

mk-table-checksum is used to generate the checksums, and is pretty simple:

```
% mk-table-checksum localhost \
        --quiet \
        --replicate=test.checksum --empty-replicate-table --create-replicate-table \
        --chunk-size=500000 --sleep-coef=0.5 \
        --ignore-tables=mysql.general_log_backup,mysql.general_log,mysql.slow_log,mysql.help_topic,mysql.tables_priv
```

These checksums are then replicated to the Replica (slave) server, where we compare the checksums.

Around a month ago we had a server failure. We fixed the server, started up the database and resumed replication. Everything seems to be working fine-- Slave_IO_Running and Slave_SQL_Running are both set to "Yes", everything appears to be getting replicated successfully except for the error mentioned below, etc.

There is one problem, however. When I check the table using the following [recommended method](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-table-checksum.html#consistent_checksums) on the Replica, I see a consistency problem.

```
# mysql --execute "SELECT db, tbl, chunk, this_cnt-master_cnt AS cnt_diff, \
>         this_crc <> master_crc OR ISNULL(master_crc) <> ISNULL(this_crc) AS crc_diff \
>         FROM test.checksum \
>         WHERE master_cnt <> this_cnt OR master_crc <> this_crc OR ISNULL(master_crc) <> ISNULL(this_crc);"
+--------+------------------+-------+----------+----------+
| db     | tbl              | chunk | cnt_diff | crc_diff |
+--------+------------------+-------+----------+----------+
| plants | trees_properties |    40 |        0 |        1 |
+--------+------------------+-------+----------+----------+
```

This problem still occurs even after force another sync on the master using [mk-table-sync](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-table-sync.html) on the master. I will probably need to replace the corrupt data by hand, but I am unclear what the actual problem is. What is a 'chunk'?

My guess is that only a handful of rows are different, and I can probably replace those rows by hand. But how can I list which rows are missing?

I realize that Maatkit has been deprecated in favor of Percona Tools. I plan to upgrade some day. But for now, "if it ain't broke, don't fix it."

Comment: mt-* is old; switch to pt-*

Answer (score 2):

I think a chunk is a set number of rows to be scanned and checksummed.

I never did like chunks because if the table order matters, each chunk could be completely different if just one row was written ahead or behind another.

Try not setting a chunk size and see if the entire table is checksummed as a whole as a opposed to each chunk checksum.

You can also run [**mk-table-sync**](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-table-sync.html) using the `--print` option and redirect to a text file to see if there is any SQL created that would have been executed to sync the slave had you used the `--execute` option. If nothing comes out into the text file from `mk-table-sync`, you will have to resort to doing physical copying (for MyISAM) or mysqldump the table and loading it on the slave (for InnoDB).

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: On both the master and replica, I ran the `mk-table-checksum` again without specifying a chunk size. The command shows that the checksum differs for both the primary and secondary. Running a `select count(*) from db.table;` shows that the table on the master and slave have the same count. This suggests that a number of rows are corrupt.

Comment: That is not necessarily corruption. Even though the Master and Slave have a table with identical row counts but a different checksum value leans more towards columnar differences. If you run `mk-table-sync --sync-to-master --print > diff.sql` on the Slave, you will most likely see a lot of `REPLACE` commands in `diff.sql`. You would `DELETEs` and `REPLACE` otherwise (on mismatched counts)

Comment: The `mk-table-sync --print` option shows me a bunch of `REPLACE` statements. When I run the script, the rows are REPLACED, but the checksum still fails and `mk-table-sync --print` shows me the same rows... it's like the REPLACE isn't replacing everything...

Comment: 1) Did you use `--sync=to-master `? 2) Did you specify a chunksize? If you did, please do not use any chunk size. (As a sidenote, I have never used chunksize for the past 4 years for either mk-table-checksum or mk-table-sync. I usually get a cleaner comparison without it).

Comment: Yes I used `--sync-to-master`, and I am not currently using a chunksize. It seems that `mk-table-sync --sync-to-master` is correctly detecting rows which are not in sync, but certain values are not being changed unless the field is quoted. If I do `mk-table-sync --sync-to-master --print > diff.sql`, and then enclose the last field for each row in quotes, it is successfully changing data on the replica. The field in question has the type `varchar(255)` and contains values like '0x0000' and '0x8900'.

Comment: I am going to guess that I ran into a bug with Maatkit, and that we should really upgrade to Percona Toolkit. My current workaround is to run `mk-table-sync --sync-to-master --print > diff.sql`, manually verify ( the rows specified in diff.sql to verify that they are different `SELECT * from ...`), edit diff.sql to quote certain values, and then import using `mysql < diff.sql`.